# Why git push origin master goes dead?

Tags: github, commit, freeze, repository

I'm stuck trying to push to one of my github repos and am not sure if something is broken or what the problem is.

My repo is here:    https://github.com/frequent/tableview

I cloned this:

```
git clone https://git.github.com/frequent/tableview
```

to have it locally, which worked ok so I have a `.git` folder inside the newly cloned `tableview` folder with plenty of files in it. I then added all my files to the `tableview` folder and on the command line:

```
git add "all my files"
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

And then nothing happens. No error, no nothing. After a few mins I `CTRL+C` to escape and tried again, but without any success. I tried re-adding re-commit, but my working directory is clean.

**Question:**
Why can't I commit. From my basic understanding, I'm not doing anything wrong am I? Or is there a problem with my repo.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try using ssh protocol, may be something's borked with your Https connection.

Comment: @Dikei: how would I do this? Just https://...

Comment: Well, you start with `git clone git@github.com:frequent/tableview.git` and everything after that will use ssh protocol automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's my internet connection. Both wlan and cable are sputtering... I will try again later and see if it works.

Comment: @Dikei - It was the connection. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a firewall? Perhaps it's blocking outgoing connections through the git port. Afaik it's the 9418 port.

Comment: Since he cloned on https, the only communication going on should be https - port 443.

Comment: No firewall. I think the internet connection is flaky at the moment. Pages are loading really slow, but that shouldn't be a problem should it?

Comment: @driis: ups, I didn't notice the https, I thought automatically that he used the git port.

Comment: It may be an authentification problem. See http://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use